# Display coefficients and standardized coefficients in modelsummary

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am trying to display both unstandardized and standardized coefficients in a table using modelsummary (incredibly useful package, by the way) in a wide format. Calculating the standardized coefficients works fine and they are displayed in the table. However, I would like to also display the unstandardized coefficients with their respective SE as well. My code so far looks something like this:

```
models = list(
  "Model X" <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars),
  "Model Y" <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl) + qsec, data = mtcars))
names(models) <-  c("Model X", "Model Y")
test <- modelsummary(models, 
                      standardize = "basic",
                      shape = term~model + statistic,
                      statistic = c("statistic", "p.value"),
                      estimate = "{estimate} ({std.error})",
                      stars = TRUE,
                      fmt = 2,
                      col.names = c("", "Std. Est.  (SE)", "t", "p", "Std. Est (SE)", "t", "p"),
                      gof_omit = 'AIC|BIC|Log.Lik.|RMSE',
                      notes = "Note: Model Y includes control variables"
                      
) %>%kable_styling(font_size = 8) %>% row_spec(0, italic = T)
test
```

At the moment, the resulting table only shows the standardized coefficients. In addition, two other questions I had:

- Stars are currently not showing, is there any possibility to show them after the p-values?
- Is it possible to give three decimals for p-values, but keep two decimals for all other columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the documentation `?modelsummary`, additional arguments not explicitly supported by the `modelsummary()` function are pushed forward to the `parameters::parameters()` function. `standardize` is one of those arguments, and it will be applied to all models.

One workaround is to extract the models into an intermediate representation by setting `output="modelsummary_list"`. Then, we can feed those back to `modelsummary` to create the final table:

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)

mod1 <- modelsummary(mod, output = "modelsummary_list")
mod2 <- modelsummary(mod, output = "modelsummary_list", standardize = "basic")

models <- list(
    "Unstandardized" = mod1,
    "Standardized" = mod2)

modelsummary(
    models,
    output = "markdown",
    stars = TRUE,
    shape = term + model ~ statistic,
    statistic = c("std.error", "p.value"),
    fmt = list(estimate = 3, p.value = 2))
```

|  |  | Est. | S.E. | p |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | Unstandardized | 28.650*** | 1.588 | 0.00 |
|  | Standardized | 0.000*** | 0.000 | 0.00 |
| hp | Unstandardized | -0.024 | 0.015 | 0.13 |
|  | Standardized | -0.273 | 0.175 | 0.13 |
| factor(cyl)6 | Unstandardized | -5.968** | 1.639 | 0.00 |
|  | Standardized | -0.416** | 0.114 | 0.00 |
| factor(cyl)8 | Unstandardized | -8.521** | 2.326 | 0.00 |
|  | Standardized | -0.713** | 0.195 | 0.00 |

**Note:**
^^ + p < 0.1, * p < 0.05, ** p < 0.01, *** p < 0.001

See the `fmt` argument above, and refer to the `?modelsummary` documentation for formatting with different digits for different statistics.

In the table above, you’ll see that the stars appear after the estimates. You can make them appear after the p values instead by using `glue` strings, but there are a couple quirks that make this process suboptimal. I opened two issues on Github to track progress on improving the situation there:

- https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/531
- https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/modelsummary/issues/532

```r
modelsummary(
    models,
    shape = term + model ~ statistic,
    estimate = "{estimate}",
    statistic = "{p.value}{stars}",
    fmt = list(estimate = 3, p.value = 2))
```

|  |  | Est. | {p.value}{stars} |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | Unstandardized | 28.650 | 0.00*** |
|  | Standardized | 0.000 | 0.00*** |
| hp | Unstandardized | -0.024 | 0.13 |
|  | Standardized | -0.273 | 0.13 |
| factor(cyl)6 | Unstandardized | -5.968 | 0.00** |
|  | Standardized | -0.416 | 0.00** |
| factor(cyl)8 | Unstandardized | -8.521 | 0.00** |
|  | Standardized | -0.713 | 0.00** |

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply and the clarification. Your workaround looks quite good. However, I was hoping to "simply" add an additional column with the (un-)standardized coefficients. Do you have any idea of how to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "simply", exactly? In Section 4.3 of my JSS article I show how to add Bonferroni-corrected p values by defining a `tidy_custom.lm()` method. You could do the same with standardized estimates. https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v103i01

Comment: With "simply" I just wanted to emphasize that even though something might look simple (i.e., adding a new column to the table), it is not really simple. Thanks for linking the article, the tidy_custom.lm() helped a lot and I was able to solve my issue (also looking at your git repository).

Comment: Got it. Yeah, sometimes things get more complicated. Honestly, in a lot of cases it makes sense to just build a data frame (perhaps with the help of `get_estimates(mod, standardize="basic")`, and the feed that data frame to `add_column`. But I'm glad you found a solution!

Comment: Sorry for annoying you again, but I tried using my solution with IV regressions (ivreg) and now I get the error that object 'estimate.unst' was not found. If I follow the steps of the tidy_custom.lm function and enter the IV model, I get a df with the respective columns that looks just like the one for a regular lm. Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: Did you redefine a new `tidy_custom.ivreg()` method? Different class; different method. Also, if you execute the same code line by line, can you get the `s[, 1]` in the same way as in the previous kind of model?

Comment: Worked perfectly, Haven't worked with these methods and functions before, but they are insanely helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using this tidy_custom.lm solution as suggested by Vincent:

```
tidy_custom.lm <- function(x, ...) {
  s <- summary(x)$coefficients
  out <- data.frame(
    term = row.names(s),
    estimate.unstd = s[,1],
    se.unstd = s[,2])
  return(out)
}
```

In the modelsummary, I adjusted the following commands:

```
statistic = c("{estimate} ({std.error})", "statistic", "p.value"),
estimate = "{estimate.unstd} ({se.unstd}) {stars}"
```